# My App icon missing in iPad 2 air with iOS 8.3

Tags: ios, ipad-2

Ever since this newest update, the app icon is missing and showing as a generic app icon on my iPad running iOS 8.3. Everything else works fine as far as I can tell. On my iPhone running the newest iOS, everything seems ok (the icon shows up). I have specified the App icon in images.xcassets. Is this an iOS bug?

Image for images.xcassets

[image]

Comment: Try reinstalling your application.

Comment: @NikitaZernov, I tried but did not work.

Comment: Try to build your application with the latest iOS SDK(8.3)

Comment: Do you have 76 x 76 px icon in your image assets? Can you post picture of your icon assets

Comment: Are you sure that you enabled the iOS 8 and later sizes in your xcassets?

Comment: @Mrunal Please take a look of my updated question.

Comment: Try to clean and then run?